# Ongoing/ persistent notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a music player. And I want to show the current song in the notification bar. Also i wanna control the music (play,pause,next) from the notification. Is there a way to do this in Flutter. I'm just  stuck at notification part.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use plugins like [this](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service) or provide custom logic for music player notification for each platform.